# How do I use the quotechar with DictReader

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting the following error in code. What am I doing wrong. Thank you.

```
TypeError: 'quotchar' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Here is my method:

```
def read_csv_fieldnames(filename, separator, quote):
    """
    Inputs:
      filename  - name of CSV file
      separator - character that separates fields
      quote     - character used to optionally quote fields
    Ouput:
      A list of strings corresponding to the field names in
      the given CSV file.
    """
    with open(filename, "rt", newline='') as csvfile:
        dict_reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile,
                                     skipinitialspace=True,
                                     delimiter=separator,
                                     quotchar=quote)


        return dict_reader.fieldnames;
```

And here is how I'm using it.

```
print(read_csv_fieldnames("isp_csv_files/table1.csv", ",", "''"))
```

Comment: maybe you need single quote `"'"`

Comment: also `quotechar` misspelled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple typo: `quotchar` should be `quotechar`. The error message pretty much tells you so.